# Decomposing arbitrary maps

Tags: functions, category-theory

Let $X$ be any set and let $f$: $X\longrightarrow X$ be any map.

Must there exist an injection $g$: $X\longrightarrow X$ such that $f=g\circ h$ for some left-inverse $h$ of $g$?

Edit: The answer is No for finite $X$. What if $X$ is infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example, take $X$ to be a finite set. Then $g$ injective implies it is bijective and $h$ must also be bijective. Thus $f$ is also bijective, which contradicts the "let $f$ be any map".

In the general case, it still doesn't work. Since $hg=Id_X$, $h$ is surjective. Therefore, $Im(f)=Im(gh)=Im(g)\cong X$ because $g$ is injective. This also contradicts the "let $f$ be any map" since $f$ could have an image with cardinality smaller than $|X|$.

Comment: Indeed, if $X$ is finite, then $f$ can only be $id$. I edited to emphasize the infinite case.

Comment: I've edited my answer to extend to the general case.

Comment: Of course. I must be tired :P